# Cannot update to 18.04 on DualBoot - "EFI System Partition (ESP) not usable"

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, uefi, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade to 18.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, but it exits the installation with the message:

```
Calculating the changes

EFI System Partition (ESP) not usable 

Your EFI System Partition (ESP) is not mounted at /boot/efi. 
Please ensure that it is properly configured and try again. 

Restoring original system state

Aborting
```

I have Windows on this machine as dual boot. Fast boot is disabled on Windows 10.

I have tried to mount it in GParted but the option is disabled...

[image: /dev/sda1 info which is ESP]

What should I do to be able to move forward?

Comment: You could start by verifying that you have a /boot/efi filesystem mounted.

Comment: it is not mounted 'I have tried to mount it in GParted but the option is disabled...'

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to mount your ESP. This should work with:

```
sudo mount /boot/efi
```

If you get an error message like

```
mount: can't find /boot/efi in /etc/fstab
```

you have to add a line to your `/etc/fstab` e.g.

```
UUID=XXXX-XXXX  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

replace the `XXXX-XXXX` with the UID of your ESP (e.g. from the output of `blkid /dev/sdxX` or from gparted (92E8-1BEE in your case))

Comment: Editing this helped me also so fix unbootable Ubuntu after accidentally deleting the Windows partition with the previous boot partition