# Unreliable Boot

Tags: boot, partitioning

I'm a Linux newbie and have an annoying boot issue with my Kubuntu 23.04 on a Dell Precision 5750.

I had to enlarge the boot partition in order to install a larger Dell Firmware Update.

Ever since the booting is unreliable and takes much longer.

First the boot will take long time while showing a single line about checking x/y blocks on the disk.

Then frequently the boot will not complete normally and instead drop me into a console and recommend that I run systemctl journal -xb.

In those logs it looks like the system fails to mount the boot disk?

If I reboot multiple times finally it works.

Also sometimes instead of the default "Ubuntu" Option I use the "Advanced" > Ubunutu generic 22.04.36 Option which seems to boot fine.

How can I investigate / fix what's going on?

Thanks for help

Update:

During an update to 23.10 this message popped up. I'll investigate how to mount the boot partition:

> EFI System Partition (ESP) not usable - Your EFI Partition (ESP) is not mounted at /boot/efi. Please ensure that it is properly configured and try again

Answer (score 1):

This answer here showed me that the UUID of my boot partition changed and I was able to update it in /etc/fstab

[Cannot update to 18.04 on DualBoot - "EFI System Partition (ESP) not usable"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008974/cannot-update-to-18-04-on-dualboot-efi-system-partition-esp-not-usable)

This seemed to fix the boot issue and also sleep works normally again.